# animation repeating when i am trying to add a view to the navigationcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I Had an application in which i am adding a view like this because i need it above the navigationbar . `

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if(appDelegate.viewcontroller==nil)
    {
        appDelegate.viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
        [animation setDuration:0.5f];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                      kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [appDelegate.viewcontroller.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"someTransition"];
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:appDelegate.viewcontroller.view];
        [appDelegate.viewcontroller viewWillAppear:YES];  
   }
    else
    {       
          CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
        [animation setDuration:0.5f];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                      kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [appDelegate.viewcontroller.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"someTransition"];        
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:appDelegate.viewcontroller.view];
        [appDelegate.viewcontroller viewWillAppear:YES];        

    }
```

it was removed with

```
self.view removefromsuperview
```

all working fine when appDelegate.viewcontroller is nil.But when it is not null when the button presses it first shows the view controller and then its again gone to up and then comes the viewcontroller again.it came first without animation then with animation.why so,can anybody help me on this?